# Note taking application for web fragments and with simultaneous saving

Tags: web, note-taking, information-management, knowledge-organization, classification

Two base functionalities:

1) taking **web fragments**:
- saving that fragment (fultext-searchable) with formating and included images
- saving meta information (URL, position of fragment in the web page, taking time, origin time if possible, some identification of my device, etc.)
- some means to attach my notices to this fragment
- ideally some means to highlight or mark some words/sentences inside that fragment

2) possibility of **simultaneous saving** bellow **data** (either as built-in function of that software or at least as some possibility to reach such functionality through scripting/plugin/macro/API/... )**:**
a) saving URL of the webpage (as in bookmarks)
b) saving source code of the webpage, including images and js/css/.. files (similar to "Save as..." function of browser)
c) saving complete raster or PDF view of the same webpage
d) if possible, saving print versions of points b) and c) - many webpages have diferently formated print version
e) if possible, asking of archiving that page on archive.org/web website (it is "Save Page Now" function there)
So, as easy, as I am now saving my bookmarks in the web browser, I would save all those data by one click ;-)

I suppose, that wanted software would have some sorting/classification/searching/tagging abilities, of course. And some printing abilities. And some exporting abilities (or at least possibility to manually browse and access saved data)

I prefer open source or freeware or licence payed one time (one payment forever, i.e. no periodic payments)

Preferred platforms: Windows/Linux/Android/OpenBSD

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about all your detail requirements (esp. 2b: saving source code of the webpage...), but I think [Evernote](https://evernote.com) covers most of what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Keep](https://keep.google.com/) can do some of that, and it is free.

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer in 2022 to a 2020 question. I started using Microsoft OneNote in 2009 for almost exactly these reasons.

At the time in 2009-2011 I needed notes that would make it easier to record enough provenance/metadata for something to stand up in court. I continue to use OneNote because it’s convenient.

OneNote is free with most Windows PC/Microsoft Office systems. OneNote has web access, and android and iPhone apps, although not all features are available on all platforms.

OneNote automatically records the URL that you copy/paste extracts from beneath the extract. It does not record the offset, although IIRC it does record the URL active when you copied, which might include a search term. (I haven’t tried it with Google snippets recording offsets.)

You can copy/paste text, with formatting, although I also found it quite useful to record screen snaps of webpages. Especially useful because OneNote can OCR those snips to make them searchable.

You can embed the entire document, e.g. as PDF or something like an HTML, adjacent to the clipping, or nearby linked.

You can annotate the clipping, highlighting, drawing boxes, etc.

OneNote does not automatically record the time of capture. But that is something that you can easily add with an AHK command.  My biggest problem with that has been coming up with a human friendly format for such metadata. I usually use collapsing paragraphs.

Shortcomings: OneNote searching is abysmal